# Sublime Text - Is there a Vim-like "Shift+J" command?

Tags: vim, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I've started using Sublime Text (3) and I am considering whether or not to purchase a license. Having always used Vim - it's quite a big change for me - that said, I quite like it.

One of the things I am curious to know about though is whether I can move the line(s) <strike>above</strike> **below** onto the current line I am on (SHIFT+J in Vim).

Slightly out of scope - is there a recommended FTP plugin I can install too?

Thank you, as always for taking the time to read and offer your support.

Ash

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. There is nothing wrong about creating two or three questions at a time.

Comment: Sublime has "vintage" mode which support vim mode - may be this is the stuff you want? Link: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/vintage.html

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [Vintage Mode Cheatsheet](https://github.com/jacob-ogre/Sublime-Vintage-cheatsheet) for ST

Comment: Thank you @dmitry_romanov - I will have a look at that.

Comment: If you don't like Vintage, check out [`Vintageous`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Vintageous) - I (and many others) prefer it over Vintage. Also, in regards to your second question, the [`SFTP`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SFTP) plugin is fantastic.

Comment: Thank you @MattDMo. I've installed SFTP as suggested (works great!). I will give Vintageous a go too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think shift+j in Vim removes a newline from the current line (and thus *joins* it with the line below), and Sublime Text has an equivalent command:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> on Mac) joins lines. e.g:

```
foo
bar
```

becomes

```
foo bar
```

when you have your cursor on the foo line and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>.

Comment: Perfect - thank you. Apologies for my post too - meant 'below' not above.